# Copy Column B and C under Column A and Repeat every 3 Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be able to convert every 3 Columns into 1 column while also selecting the three columns and sorting left to right based on header name.

Original

CBAFEDIGH

Output

ADG

BEH

CFI

I have the following code to allow me to be able to convert into one column, but it doesn't limit it to the three columns and repeat every three. I am still trying to figure out the i = and Step 3

I know the sort can be setup via a script when processing the 3 columns. Just need a little help on this one.

Option Explicit

```
Sub COLMERGE()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim lrX As Long
    lrX = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lc As Long
    lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To lc
    lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(lrX, i)).Cut Range("A" & lr + 1)
    Next i
    Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, lc)).ClearContents
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm  confused by your example.  You list your column data as `C B A F E D I G H` and then state that you want the first output to be `ADG`, which is the third, sixth, and eigth columns, not 3, 6, and 9 as I would expect from your description.  Then you state the second output should be `BEH` which are the second, fifth, and ninth columns, not the 2, 5, 8 expected from your description.  And `CFI` is 1st, 4th, and 7th so it's the only one that *does* match your description.  Can you please clarify??

Comment: Column output would be ADG with column A now having  columns B and C under it, then Column B would have E and H under it and so fourth. I hope that helps.

Comment: But why is it ADG instead of ADH?  Per your description, it *should* be ADH, not ADG

Comment: I am going to reference columns with numbers. So Column 1 -  A, B, C; Column 2 - D, E, F; Column 3 - G, H, I. I am hoping that this makes a little more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the columns to process properly with the below code

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColMerge()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim lrX As Long
    lrX = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lc As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To lc Step 3

    Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(31, i)).Cut Range(Cells(32, i - 1), Cells(61, i - 1))
    Range(Cells(2, i + 1), Cells(31, i + 1)).Cut Range(Cells(62, i - 1), Cells(91, i - 1))

    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox ("Completed")

End Sub
```

I was able to get the sort by using the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReSort_LtoR()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim lrX As Long
    lrX = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lc As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To lc Step 3

    Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(31, i + 2)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(1, i + 2)), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort
        .SetRange Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(31, i + 2))
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox ("Completed")

End Sub
```